# WinJs: Ignore Font scaling from Windows

Tags: windows, uwp, winjs, dpi

I've developed a WinJs app for the Surface pro 4. The app Runs in fullscreen and is layoutet with the screen resolution of 2736x1824 (surface resolution).

Now when i start the App on the surface the DPI scaling comes into play and messes up my Layout.

Is there a way to disable the scaling for the app?

I've tried:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewScaling.trySetDisableLayoutScaling(true);
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, making your app layout only for one resolution, especially for such a big resolution is not really great idea since the app can run on device with, for example 1920x1080 resolution where even with DPI scaling disabled your layout will be messed up.

So I recommend making the app layout responsive so it will look right on every resolution.

Comment: i'm totally aware of that, but my app only has to run on one device. It will be a kiosk mode app. Also i have total control of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking at this issue but I've found that the code that you see all over the place is actually XBox only ([Link To Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewscaling#Methods))

And the Microsoft Devs have been saying for a while that it's a user based setting and they don't plan on allowing you to ds([Forum Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/314f03ae-6b27-4f4a-acb5-c67d3372238c/windows-store-app-for-surface-pro-resolution?forum=winappswithcsharp#bcb89e65-929d-4396-b120-60a76e125dce))

You can detect the scaling value though with `ResolutionScale` ([docsLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.resolutionscale))

`Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.getForCurrentView().resolutionScale`

[Here's a link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DpiScaling) to a sample that detects it and adjusts.

So what you can do (and what I did) was where needed I used css scale to adjust the system to fit. Most of my app is responsive so it didn't matter, but if you use an iFrame and set it to be 1000px wide with this scale factor it will actually be 1400px or even 1800px wide and totally cut off..

I have listeners setup for the resize events and just adjust as needed.

Hope that helps!

-Dennis